# How does SQL MAX() works?

Tags: mysql, max

SQL MAX should be very easy to understand, but why my this query does not work as expected?

Here is the schema and data

```
CREATE TABLE orders(
    id INT,
    name TEXT,
    quantity INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES 
    (1, 'abc', 10), 
    (2, 'def', 3), 
    (3, 'abc', 2),
    (4, 'ghi', 4),
    (5, 'ghi', 7),
    (6, 'ghi', 13);
```

This is the query

```
select t.name, max(t.avgq) from (
    select name, avg(quantity) as avgq 
    from orders group by name
) as t;
```

The result I got from mysql and sqlfiddle are all like this

```
name    max(t.avgq)
-----+-------------
abc        8
```

Where it should actually be

```
name    max(t.avgq)
-----+--------------
ghi        8
```

Why is that?

Comment: MySQL doesn't work like other dbms products (or the SQL standard) when it comes to group by.

Comment: but sqlfiddle does not work as well...

Comment: Even this simple one does not work

 select name, max(quantity) from orders;

It returns 

        abc 13

Comment: According to the SQL standard, the query is invalid (and it does not run) because the value to select for `t.name` is indeterminate. MySQL accepts the query and gets you some value from the `name` column.

Comment: could you point me to that SQL standard documentation? many thanks

Comment: @BeNdErR, the orders.name with the highest average is "ghi"
ghi has three quantity: 4,7,13 which results in avg = 8

Comment: @vcharlie sorry, I didn't pay too much attention to the inner query.

Comment: @vcharlie you are doing a partial `GROUP BY` since t.name is not present inside the group by clause. Also, this query is non standard and only works in MySQL.

Comment: See GROUP BY in the (MySQL) manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MAX()` will return only the maximum value for that column, it doesn't affect the other columns. To get your desired result you need to run the following:

```
SELECT name, AVG(quantity) as avgq 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY AVG(quantity) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This will not guaranteed to produce correct results. If it does, it is purely by chance.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, I know we can do that, but I have always though that 

    SELECT field1, max(field2) from table;

should works fine? or maybe my sql knowledge is so wrong?

Comment: Well, not in MySQL. As others already mentioned, this will return the first value for field1 and the max value for field 2, these do not have to be related.

Comment: Actually I can do it with a query like this 
`SELECT name from orders WHERE name = (SELECT MAX(avg_qunatity) FROM (SELECT AVG(quantity) AS avg_quantity FROM orders GROUP BY name))`  but it is so tedious

Answer (score 4):

According to the SQL standard, your outer query is not correct.

Because you use the aggregate function [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) without a `GROUP BY` clause, an implicit `GROUP BY ()` is assumed (both by the SQL99 standard and) by MySQL:

> If you use a group function in a statement containing no `GROUP BY` clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.

*(source: [12.18.1 GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html))*

You can use `t.name` in the `SELECT` clause only if any of these happens:

- it also appears in the `GROUP BY` clause;
- it is used as an argument of a [`GROUP BY` aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html);
- it is [functionally dependent](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) on a column that appears in the `GROUP BY` clause.

MySQL accepts queries whose `SELECT` fields do not follow the rules of `GROUP BY` enumerated above but, in this case, the values returned for these fields are indeterminate:

> ... a `MySQL` extension to the use of `GROUP BY` is to permit the select list, `HAVING` condition, or `ORDER BY` list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on `GROUP BY` columns. This causes `MySQL` to accept the (...) query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want.

*(source: [12.18.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html))*

#### A query that works

You can keep the inner query, order the resulting rows descending by `AVG(quantity)` and use another `MySQL` extension of the SQL standard (i.e. `LIMIT`) to get only the first value (which is the maximum after ordering).

The query is:

```
SELECT name, AVG(quantity) AS avgq 
FROM orders
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY avgg DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Note: `MAX` *can* be used without a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination

Answer (score 1):

The query you use isn't actually valid. You should aggregate all columns that aren't grouped. In this case it applies to `t.name`.

Unlike other, more strict, database systems, MySQL allows this query to be ran and takes the very first value they encounter for the `t.name` field. This may differ when `grouping`, or maybe the execution plan, causes the data set to be sorted differently.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.name, max(t.avgq) from (
    select name, avg(quantity) as avgq 
    from orders group by name
) as t;
```

correct me if I am wrong

- whenever we are using any column with an aggregate function in the select query, that column should be part of the group by clause to avoid ambiguity.

so correct query can be

```
select  t.name , max(t.avgq)from (
    select name, avg(quantity) as avgq 
    from table3 group by name
) as t
group by t.name,t.avgq
having t.avgq =(select max(tq.avgq) from (
    select name, avg(quantity) as avgq 
    from table3 group by name
)tq);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to use `MAX()` function, but @Paul answer is better

```
select name, avg_quantity 
from (
   select name, avg(quantity) as avg_quantity from orders group by name
) as avg_table 
inner join (
   select max(avg_quantity) as avg_quantity 
   from (
      select name, avg(quantity) as avg_quantity from orders group by name) as avg_table
   ) as max_table USING (avg_quantity);
```